# How to move LocalDB mdf files

Tags: c++, localdb

Could you please help me look into this issue?

**Steps**:

1. User **Administrator** created a LocalDB file under C:\Users\Public\Documents\MyDB
2. Moved the file to C:\Users**Admin**\MyDB

that is, the mdf file was moved from user to user.

**Result**: After moving, the file cannot be opened in my program, the openEx function throws an exception.

**Error msg**: **An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file "...\myDb.mdf" failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.**

[image]

I made sure that the admin user had full control permissions and inherited permissions during the move.